# Jquery to parent div of slide show only

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am working on some jquery where I have a slide show of different images fade in and out.

The problem is that within the slide show div I have another child div that I don't want to fade in and out.

I am trying to get the wording "test" in the jfiddle below to stay on, whilst the image below fades in and out. If i can get that to work then I can adapt it for my website.

It's critical that only the parent div fades in and out and not the child div.

[Jfiddle so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/4TZ29/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/4TZ29/12/)

```
#slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}

<div id='slideshow'><div>testtest</div></div>


var imgArray = ['http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/59/500_x_300_Ramosmania_rodriguesii_(Rubiaceae).jpg', 
                 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/New-Withrow-Gym-500-X-300.jpg', 
                 'http://inspirationfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/22551-500x300.jpg', 
                 'http://inspirationfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/11619912483527701-500x300.jpg', 
                 'http://westernstatescat.com/system/images/BAhbBlsHOgZmIigyMDExLzEyLzIwLzA5LzAwLzMzLzgwNi81MDB4MzAwLmpwZw/500x300.jpg'
               ]
var nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)] + ") no-repeat bottom center";
$('#slideshow').css("background", nextBG);              

setInterval(function(){
    nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)] + ") no-repeat bottom center";
    $('#slideshow').fadeOut('slow', function() { 
        $(this).css("background", nextBG).fadeIn('slow'); })                   
}, 3000); // 3 second interval
```

Comment: Move `<div>testtest</div>` so it doesn't fade — you are fading the parent element `#slidedhow`, and this will cause all child elements to follow the fading effect. Move it one level up the DOM tree to stop that.

Comment: The problem is that I need to have a child div for the slideshow div as my website will have a menu within the slideshow div.

Comment: I basically have a header menu 918x416px where I want the background image alternating as a slideshow.

Comment: Why does the menu has to be IN the slideshow in the sense that it must be a child of the slideshow element? You can position the menu absolutely over the slideshow if you really want it to be visually in the latter.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to achieve www.printingtoday.co.uk. I just figured this was the best way as I'm using opencart. I've used absolute on the home page before and it threw things out.

Comment: Can't you simply position the slideshow on the left, and the menu on the right? It is as simple as floating them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

The parent div will always fade out the child because of the way the DOM works. Absolute positioning controlled via js might work for you. For example:

```
function positionText () {
    var x = $('#text-div').height(),
    y = $('#text-div').width(),
    z = $('#slide-container').offset().top,
    i = $('#slide-container').offset().left,
    h = $('#slide-container').height(),
    w = $('#slide-container').width();
    $('#text-div').css({top: z + ( (h / 2) - (x / 2) ), left: i + ( (w / 2) - (y / 2) )});
}
```

Call positionText() every time your slide-container width changes.

***Make sure #text-div has position:absolute and z-index:2 for good measure***

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id='slideshow'></div>
  <div id="childText">testtest</div>
</div>
```

And add css like:

```
#slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
}
#childText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
#parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

which is positioning the childtext absolute and keeping it in center. Hope this helps.